# Database Design for Contacts

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

So I have 3 main entities.  Airports, Customers, and Vendor.

Each of these will have multiple contacts I need to relate to each.

So they way I set it up currently.

I have the following tables..

- `Airport`
- `Customer`
- `Vendor`

I then have one Contacts table and a xref for Airport, Customer, Vendor...

I am questioning that and was thinking a contacts table for each ..

- Airport and AirportContacts
- Customer and CustomerContacts
- Vendor and VendorContacts

Any drawbacks to either of these designs?

Comment: assuming a contact can only correlate with one entity, go for contacts table with a contact type column. assuming a contact can correlate with multiple entities, well, either a delimiter string of contact types (quick and dirty solution) or a table which holds the mappings.

Comment: It really depends on how you use your contacts.  If frequently, in queries, you would treat all contacts together often, then having them as a single table might make the most sense.

Comment: Yes..I forgot the mention the single contact table design had a a type column.

Comment: @Y.S I would recommend NOT using a delimited string for *anything* in a database, a large number of questions on SO are about how to fix a design that has decided to use these @S

Comment: @Milney thanks, noted, like I wrote, quick and dirty... sometimes time to market wins the build it right from start battle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, the deciding factor is duplication of entities vs "one version of the truth".  If a single real-world person can be a contact for more than one of the other entities, then you don't want to store that single person in multiple contact tables, because then you have to maintain any changes to his/her properties in multiple places.

If you put the same "Joe Smith" in both `AirportContacts` and `VendorContacts`, then one day when you look and see his city is "Denver" in one table and "Boston" in another table, which one will you consider to be the truth?

But as someone mentioned in comments, if a contact can only be associated with one of the three other entities ("types" as you call them), then putting them in separate tables makes the most sense.

And there's yet a third scenario.   Say "Joe Smith" can be a contact for both Airports and Vendors.   But say that he has some properties, like his gender and age, which are the same regardless of which "type" he is being considered, but there might be some properties, like phone number, or position/job title, which could depend on the "type".   Maybe he uses one phone in his capacity as an Airport Vendor, and a different phone as a Vendor Contact.  Moreover, maybe there are some properties that apply to one type of contact that don't apply to the others.   In these cases, I would look at some kind of hybrid approach where you keep common properties in a single Contact table, and "Type"-specific properties in their own type-related tables.   These type-related tables would be bridge tables that have FKs back to the Contact table and to the main entity table of the "Type" they are related to (Vendor, Customer or Airport).

Comment: Thank you for this response. Many of these questions is what prompted me to post here.  Unfortunately I am having a tough time getting the correct clarification from the business unit and trying to move the project along with the limited information I have been given so far.  I guess once I get that kind of feedback, I can make a decision and move forward.

Answer (score 0):

What I have so far ... Dont mind some of the data types.. just placed quick placeholders..
[image]